# Email reception directing the domain request to EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mx-record, godaddy

I'm not able to receive any emails on my GoDaddy hosted domain after changing the DNS settings for redirecting the domain request to an AWS EC2 instance.

Even though it's a common scenario, I would like to know is there any chances to redirect only the HTTP & HTTPS request to the ec2 instance and the incoming mail requests to the GoDaddy mail server?

Comment: Research `MX` records and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set your A records to point at your web server and your MX records to point at the email server. Where is your email hosted? You may need to purchase email hosting separately - google apps, fastmail, zohomail, or Godaddy.